# Is it possible to print both the data and count of the data in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a huge SQL query with multiple sub-tables (sub-table output is not retained) that is generating a final output in a specific format (format is fixed as it is expected by another service). I want to also generate some counts of the sub-tables in the query. A simple solution would be to re-write and run the query again, and get the counts.
However, I want to avoid double executions/computations of the same things and don't want to store the sub-tables either. I want to be able to either append these counts to the data output (will need to modify the service to ignore these count values accordingly) OR be able to write these counts to another location.
I'm using 'unload to S3' command (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html), where all the results are stored in a S3 location.

Is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

Comment: You can save the results to a temporary table, then generate counts from that.

Comment: Counting is an aggregation, therefore even if you execute it via a subquery in the same select statement, the subquery runs separately. The only way to avoid double execution is to count the rows of the resultset.

Comment: Amazon Redshift supports [window functoins](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html). Add `COUNT(*) OVER ()` to the output list - and this column will provide total rows amount in the output in any output row.